# Waiting for signal

Tags: c, signals

I want my program to wait for a signal which will be SIGUSR1, but currently does not work.

The class that will catches the signal:

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int pid;
    pid=getpid();
    printf("PID: %d\n", pid);

    pause();

    void my_handler(int signum)
    {
        if (signum == SIGUSR1)
        {
            printf("Received SIGUSR1!\n");
        }
    }

    signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);
}
```

Program that will give the signal:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i;

    printf("Filename: %s, Receiver PID: %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1], "w");

    kill(atol(argv[1]),SIGUSR1);

}
```

You would first run the receiver like `./receiver 1`
then after you find the PID(ex 3375) of the receiver you would run `./signaler 1 3375`

Pause is the function i'm using to wait but it's not working, would sigwaitinfo or sigsuspend work?

Comment: Is this a poor cut/paste or do you have your signal handler nested within main()? Among other problems, `argv[2]` would be the PID to pass to `kill`, not `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the formatting makes checking this difficult, but it looks like you are calling signal() **after** pause(). You need to move the signal call to the top of main, or at least before pause.